# In memory database disposed by the initial use

Tags: c#, entity-framework, in-memory-database, objectdisposedexception

I'm trying to use In-Memory Database. I can read from it, but if I try to add something it throws an exception of type `System.ObjectDisposedException`.I cant really spot differences with working examples around. I'm using `EF Core`, `.net core 3.1`. Also, I'm using it along with a repository pattern where currently I have a single repository.
Startup :

```
 services.AddDbContext<WeirdContext>(options =>
 {
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("WeirdDb")
           .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
           .ConfigureWarnings(b => b.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning));                
 });

 services.AddTransient<IMyOnlyRepository, MyOnlyRepository>();
```

repository:

```
 private readonly WeirdContext _context;

 public ShowtimesRepository(WeirdContext context)
 {
     _context = context;
 }

 public ShowtimeEntity Add(WeirdEntity weirdEntity)
 {
     context.Showtimes.Add(showtimeEntity);
     var id =_context.SaveChanges();
     return GetCollection(ent => ent.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
 }
...
```

how it's being consumed in a service:

```
public async void Create(WeirdModel weirdModel)
{
    var extraDataModel = await imdbService.fetchSomestuff(weirdModel.Id);
    weirdModel.extraData = mapper.Map<extraData>(extraDataModel); // mapping goes well
    var weirdEntity = mapper.Map<WeirdEntity>(weirdModel);
    WeirdRepository.Add(showtimeEntity);
 }
```

And the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] WeirdModel weirdModel)
{
    showtimeService.Create(weirdModel);
    return StatusCode(201); 
}
```

Can someone spot what's off?

Comment: _"Also, I'm using it along with a repository pattern"_ <-- When you're using EF you _should not_ implement any kind of repository pattern yourself (imo, it's an anti-pattern, but I digress) because your `DbContext` **already is** a unit-of-work and its constitutent `DbSet<T>` **already is** a generic-repository in itself.

Comment: Please show us the `StackTrace` of the `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: What do the constructors for your controller and your service look like?